# preloading animated gifs to use in rollover image. In ie, when i mouse over, the animation jumps to current frames

Tags: javascript, button, gif, rollover, animated

Is there a way other than not preloading animated gifs for rollover buttons so that when you rollover the button, the animated gif starts at the beginning of the gif animation.

Firefox starts at the beginning of the animations when rolling over. IE starts at the position the preloaded image is at when you rollover the button.

Using javascript in the head to preload all images.

any takers?

ps: if there is a better way to approach this project, maybe non-animated gifs, do point me in the right direction. link to site below.

[test site](http://terrydennissoper.com/steve/)

Comment: If I understand your problem, IE's behavior is the issue? If so, you could just sniff for IE and have a different function run. Alternatively, you could look into sprite sheets.

Comment: Thanks Nikki.  Sprites look interesting.

Comment: sprites does the job thxs!